# Unknown option --extractCss in AspNetCore Angular 6.0 SPA Template

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, angular6

I have scaffolded `AspNetCore Angular 6.0 SPA template` from `cli` and then installed `npm` package accordingly.

However when i try to run the project `dotnet run` it does not start rather prompted with and error. I have captured a screenshot for your reference. I am not sure whether it is something to do with `angular.Json` file or else!!! Any idea..

**Error:**

> Unknown option --extractCss

[image: Error Captured]

Comment: Is there are `angular.json` file ? If yes, show the file

Comment: Yes Angular.Json file is pretty much present in its directory. The problem is only when i try to run from dotnet cli, however when i try to change the folder path to ClientApp and use angular cli it works fine. "ng serve -o". The only problem is with dotnet cli.

Answer (score 27):

This is because the `ng serve` command no longer supports `--extractCss` option

Open `package.json`. You'll find

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css" // Please remove the --extract-css
    // ...
  }  
}
```

remove the `--extract-css` from `start` scripts.

It'll be now

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "start": "ng serve"
      // ...
  }   
}
```

Now open `angular.json`. set `"extractCss": true` in `build` configuration

example:

```
"build": {
    "architect": {
           "configurations": {
                "extractCss": true,
                  //...
             }
         }
      }
   }
```

**Reference:** https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10666#issuecomment-386843570

**Reference 2:** http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-5-app-angular-6-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: this is the only answer that solved my problem (VS2017 + .net core 2.1 + Angular 6.2.4)