# .NET Core Angular project controller's single-param-constructor causing error

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular-cli

I created a new .Net-Core Angular project following the wizard in VS2017, then I added a new constructor with a single param within the controller like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{
    private readonly string name;

    public SampleDataController(string something)
    {
        name = something;
    }

    public SampleDataController()
    {

    }

    //Some other actions
}
```

I did a bit tests on this block of code:

1. When there is only the default constructor, it works fine. along with the un-used private string.
2. It no longer works when the single-param-constructor appears, with or without the default constructor.

NB: Well, if you have problems debugging a newly created angular project in VS2017, have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415679/unknown-option-extractcss-in-aspnetcore-angular-6-0-spa-template/50417099#50417099)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the default constructor, the runtime will try to create an instance via the single-param-constructor. Then, most likely, the runtime don't know how to resolve the string dependency to create the controller.

Therefore, In your ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs, enable the registration of controllers as services and then register the dependency

```
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
services.AddTransient(ctx => new SampleDataController("your string value"));
```